# Generic Extension method for LINQ JOIN using 2 columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics, join

I have created a generic `extension` method to join 2 `tables` based upon one common column. The code is as follows:

```
public class SomeDTO<T,U>
    {
        public T TableA { get; set; }
        public U TableB { get; set; }
    }
    public static class Helper
    {
        public static IQueryable<SomeDTO<T,U>> JoinExtension<T,U,Key>(this IQueryable<T> tableA, IQueryable<U> tableB, Expression<Func<T,Key>> columnA, Expression<Func<U,Key>> columnB)
        {
            return tableA.Join(tableB, columnA, columnB,(x, y) => new SomeDTO<T, U>{TableA = x,TableB = y});
        }
    }
```

Now the tables in the `database` have 2 common columns (Id, Type), I need to write a common extension method to join these tables based upon the 2 common columns, wrote something as below:

```
    public static IQueryable<SomeDTO<T, U>> JoinExtensionTwoColumns<T, U, Key>(this IQueryable<T> tableA, IQueryable<U> tableB, Expression<Func<T, Key>> columnA, Expression<Func<U, Key>> columnB, Expression<Func<T, Key>> columnC, Expression<Func<U, Key>> columnD)
   {
    return tableA.Join(tableB, a => new { columnA, columnB }, b => new { columnC, columnD }, (a, b) => new SomeDTO<T, U> { TableA = a, TableB = b });
   }
```

Compiler gives me an error stated as below at the line of code `tableA.Join`.... as below:

```
The type arguments for method 'Queryable.Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IQueryable<TOuter>, IEnumerable<TInner>, Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>>, Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>>, Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

It's not able to understand the `arguments` and their nature correctly.

Any pointers to where I maybe going wrong?

**EDIT:**

I now have a method which compiles successfully, but I get a runtime error that
 "`The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`"

```
public static IQueryable<SomeDTO<T, U>> JoinExtensionTwoColumns<T, U, Key>(this IQueryable<T> tableA, IQueryable<U> tableB, Expression<Func<T, Key>> columnA, Expression<Func<U, Key>> columnB, Expression<Func<T, Key>> columnC, Expression<Func<U, Key>> columnD)
        {
return tableA.Join(tableB, a => new object[]{ columnA, columnB }, b => new object []{ columnC, columnD }, (a, b) => new SomeDTO<T, U> { TableA = a, TableB = b });
}
```

Calling the method as such:

```
var result= (db.table1.JoinExtensionTwoColumns<table1,table2,int>(db.table2, c => c.id.ToString(), d => d.id.ToString(),e => e.type, f => f.type)).Take(10);
```

Any more pointers.

Comment: You have an anonymous type which requires a name : new { columnA, columnB } (2 places).  You can also use object instead : new object[] { columnA, columnB } .  Any type will automatically cast to an object, but you need to cast when assigning type object to a specific type.

Comment: @jdweng..I have tried what you have said. No compiler error though, but a runtime error 'The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.'. I am trying to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: @jdweng: Please see the edit and give some pointers. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already done all work: `JoinExtensionTwoColumns` method is not needed, you can use `JoinExtension` for joining tables based on **several** columns:

```
tableA.JoinExtension<TypeA, TypeB, object>(tableB, x => new { x.column1, x.column2 }, 
    x => new { column1 = x.column2, column2 = x.column3  });
```

But at this case - solution **not TypeSafely** due to third **arbitrary** - `object` type parameter, to fix it, you may refactor previous solution this way:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public class JoinCondition<TFirst, TSecond>
    {            
        public TFirst column1 { get; set; }
        public TSecond column2 { get; set; }
    }

    public static IQueryable<SomeDTO<T, U>> JoinExtension<T, U, TFirst, TSecond>(this IQueryable<T> tableA, IQueryable<U> tableB, 
        Expression<Func<T, JoinCondition<TFirst, TSecond>>> joinSelectorA, 
        Expression<Func<U, JoinCondition<TFirst, TSecond>>> joinSelectorB)
    {
        return tableA.Join(tableB, joinSelectorA, joinSelectorB, (x, y) => new SomeDTO<T, U> { TableA = x, TableB = y });
    }
}
```

**Implementaion:**

```
var answer = context.TableA.JoinExtension(context.TableB, 
    x => new Helper.JoinCondition<int, string> { column1 = x.prop1, column2 = x.prop2}, 
    x => new Helper.JoinCondition<int, string> { column1 = x.prop3, column2 = x.prop4}
    ).ToList();
```

> P.S. `JoinExtensionTwoColumns` method contains mistakes: you use
>   columnA, columnB and etc as columns, but they are predicates, you can
>   fix it this way(**it will not work at EF context**):

```
public static IQueryable<SomeDTO<T, U>> JoinExtensionTwoColumns<T, U, Key>(this IQueryable<T> tableA, IQueryable<U> tableB, 
    Expression<Func<T, Key>> columnA, Expression<Func<U, Key>> columnB, 
    Expression<Func<T, Key>> columnC, Expression<Func<U, Key>> columnD)
{
    return tableA.Join(tableB, 
        a => new { column1 = columnA.Compile()(a), column2 = columnC.Compile()(a) }, 
        b => new { column1 = columnB.Compile()(b), column2 = columnD.Compile()(b) }, 
        (a, b) => new SomeDTO<T, U> { TableA = a, TableB = b });
}
```

Comment: @Slava...Thanks for the answer.Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: @Slava...Your edit to the JoinExtensionTwoColumns generates a runtime error though 'The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.'. Any ideas on it? Meanwhile i am trying your first approach.

Comment: This error occur, because you probably perform this query at EF context. Of course, it will happen, but you not specify this fact at you question. If you will try this approach on simple `List<T>` collections all will be work.

Comment: @Slava..I understand you..Let me try.

Comment: @Slava..I have to use EF context itself, the JoinExtensionTwoColumns is called on db.Table1 and db.Table2..I cant convert them to list and then do. Any more ideas. Also, the first approach fails    "tableA.JoinExtension(tableB, x => new { x.column1, x.column2 }, 
    x => new { column1 = x.column2, column2 = x.column3  });", because  columns are of type int and string and there is typecasting error coz we are using anonymous types.

Comment: You should specify ef tag on your question at firstly. Are you have this error at compile time or runtime and specify types of all columns.

Comment: @Slava..Added EF tag, Having error at runtime.Thanks

Comment: @Slava..Please see EDIT.

Comment: I edited implementation of `JoinExtension` (types are specified  explicitly). Also it was tested by me and it is working at EF.

Comment: @Slava..Thanks..i hv accepted ur answer..If I wana have a where clause..how should I proceed at it. I am giving a sample with WHERE clause as well. Is it the correct way?? tableA.JoinExtension<TypeA, TypeB, object>(tableB, x => new { x.column1, x.column2 }, 
    x => new { column1 = x.column2, column2 = x.column3  }).Where(a=>a.tableA.someID.Equals("12000"));